# Check if X = Y, if yes, aplly CSS on Z div

Tags: jquery, css

Before all, I did try to search for a solution on both Google and Stackoverflow, but nothing helped /or i'm a bad searcher/.

It's quite simple but i'm not qualified nor good enough to do it by myself.
I'm looking for a way (jQuery or not) to check if X = Y, and if it is the case, then apply a specific class on Z.

Any idea ?
Thanks !

Comment: It it a very tough world my friend!

Comment: I have tried multiple codes I found on some websites -including Stackoverflow- but none worked. :l

Comment: @mSyx you have got good answer but still to use jquery don't forget to add jquery min file in your code.

Comment: Sure mate ! I already did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very simple my friend (use [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/)), you should try it out:

```js
var A = 1;
var B = 1;
if(A == B) { // Matching the conditions (if they are equal)
  // If they are equal, then add a class using jQuery's addClass Method!
  $('.Z').addClass('myClass');
}
```

```css
.myClass{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!---- HTML Code ----->
<div class="A">A</div>
<div class="B">B</div>
<div class="Z">Z</div>
```

> The jQuery's [`addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) method adds the specified class(es) to each
>   element in the set of matched elements.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @SaumyaRastogi better include jquery link too so user won't get confused that why jquery part is not running.

Comment: I do have some experience in CSS and HTML, and a little bit of JS/jQuery so I should be able to understand how it works. :>

I thought I could do the next thing, but well. I just can't.
**Is it possible to check if the value of the attribute of div X is the same as div Y ?**

Comment: Yup, but if the X and Y divs should be a form input like this - `<input type="text" value="1" class="X">`, so you can grab their value as `$('.X').val()`

Comment: I'm sorry. I badly explained the situation, even though I understand your reply. This is what i've been trying to do for a few hours (example) :

<div class="derp" data-test="1">1</div>
<div class="meme" data-test="1">2</div>

If "data-test" from both divs are the same, then it should add class to another div.
(sorry for bothering and thank you for your help)

Comment: Bwah, doesn't work. I must suck.
Here's my last attempt

$(function() {
        $('body').attr('data-usern', _userdata["username"]);
        $('.ls_bloc').attr('data-username', _userdata["username"]);

  var A = $('body').attr("data-usern");
  var B = $('.ls_bloc').attr("data-username");

if(A == B) {
  $(B).addClass('myClass'); }
});

Any idea ? <:

Answer (score 0):

There Is two way you can add it by Jquery

1. You can add `css` through `class` in jquery using `addClass()`.

   ```
   if(X== Y)
   { 
     $("#Z").addClass("yourclass")
   }
   ```
2. You can directly add it in jquery by using `css()`

   ```
   $("#Z").css("color","red")
   ```

Answer (score 0):

So you meen something like this?

```
<div id="some_id" class="Some classes"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var choose = 'Y';
    if(choose == 'Y') {
        $("#some_id").addClass("className");
    }
});
</script>
```